# DataTable takes enormous time to display even for 100 entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am inserting values into a `DataTable` dynamically. I have some 100s of rows and it is taking around 8-10 secs to load the DataTable. Is there a way to make this faster?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdqjqbbp/)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a significantly improved version. I guess 50 times faster.

```js
for (var i=0, l=md.length; i<l; i++) { 
  var thisRow = [], x = md[i]
  thisRow.push('<u><a target="_blank" href="' + x.Data[0].Link + '">' + x.Data[0].Value + '</a></u>');
  for(var k=1; k<x.Data.length; k++){
    thisRow.push(x.Data[k].Value);
  }
  t.row.add(thisRow) 
  if (i == l-1) t.draw()
}
```

- use a `for`-loop with known limit `l` instead of the extremely expensive `$.each`
- `draw()` only once, when the insertion of rows is finished

updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/pdqjqbbp/1/**

Comment: Thank you @davidkonrad ! This solution really helped me :)